# How to Draw on rotated canvas using mouse?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to draw on img its work fine but when i rotate the image its drawing axis is total change and it not draw on the right area

https://codepen.io/ali-shahzil/project/editor/AddPLW

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;
var SCALE_MIN = 1,
  SCALE_MAX = 25;
var currScale = 0; // def pic width=600px, 100px=1scale unit
var xscale = 1.0;
var scaleFactor = 1.00;
var painting = false,
  mark = true,
  lastX = 0,
  lastY = 0,
  lineThickness = 0.3,
  width = 600,
  height = 600;

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'img.JPG';

img.onload = function() {

  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.height = height;
  canvas.width = width;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 5, 40, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.height = height;
  canvas.width = width;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 5, 40, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  canvas = ctx = ''; //reset

}

function doMarking() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("mark");

  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    mark = true;
    if (canvas != null)
      canvas.style.cursor = "pointer";
    //currImgId = '';
  } else {
    mark = false;
    if (canvas != null);
    canvas.style.cursor = "";
  }

  lastX = 0,
    lastY = 0,
    painting = false;

}

function mouseDown(e) {

  if (!mark)
    return;
  painting = true;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
  lastX = e.pageX - (e.target).offsetLeft;
  lastY = e.pageY - (e.target).offsetTop;
  //Calculating the scale how much it increase
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); // abs. size of element
  scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width; // relationship bitmap vs. element for X
  scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height; // relationship bitmap vs. element for Y
  lastX = lastX * scaleX;
  lastY = lastY * scaleY;

  //console.log('Before lasX=' + lastX + ' lastY=' + lastY+',currScale='+currScale);

  //lastX=transformSimple(lastX);
  // lastY=transformSimple(lastY);

  //console.log('After lasX=' + lastX + ' lastY=' + lastY+', currScale='+currScale);
  //console.log('offleft=' + (e.target).offsetLeft + ', offsetTop=' + (e.target).offsetTop);
  // console.log('e=' + e);
}
/*
        canvas1.onmousedown=function (e) {
            console.log('mousedown2 id=' + e);
            if (!mark)
                return;
            painting = true;
            ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
            lastX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            lastY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    
            console.log('lasX=' + lastX + ' lastY=' + lastY);
        }
        */
function mouseUp(e) {

  if (!mark)
    return;

  painting = false;
}

function mouseMove(e) {
  if (!mark)
    return;
  if (painting) {
    mouseX = e.pageX - (e.target).offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.pageY - (e.target).offsetTop;
    //Calculating the scale how much it increase
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); // abs. size of element
    scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width; // relationship bitmap vs. element for X
    scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height; // relationship bitmap vs. element for Y
    mouseX = mouseX * scaleX;
    mouseY = mouseY * scaleY;

    //    mouseX=transformSimple(mouseX);
    //    mouseY=transformSimple(mouseY);

    //console.log('mx=' + mouseX + ', my=' + mouseY);
    // find all points between        
    var x1 = mouseX,
      x2 = lastX,
      y1 = mouseY,
      y2 = lastY;


    var steep = (Math.abs(y2 - y1) > Math.abs(x2 - x1));
    if (steep) {
      var x = x1;
      x1 = y1;
      y1 = x;

      var y = y2;
      y2 = x2;
      x2 = y;
    }
    if (x1 > x2) {
      var x = x1;
      x1 = x2;
      x2 = x;

      var y = y1;
      y1 = y2;
      y2 = y;
    }

    var dx = x2 - x1,
      dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1),
      error = 0,
      de = dy / dx,
      yStep = -1,
      y = y1;

    if (y1 < y2) {
      yStep = 1;
    }

    lineThickness = 5 - Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)) / 10;
    if (lineThickness < 1) {
      lineThickness = 1;
    }

    for (var x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
      if (steep) {

        // translate(y,x);

        ctx.fillRect(y, x, lineThickness, lineThickness);
        //ctx.fillRect(transformSimple(y), transformSimple(x), lineThickness, lineThickness);


      } else {
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, lineThickness, lineThickness);


      }

      error += de;
      if (error >= 0.5) {
        y += yStep;
        error -= 1.0;
      }
      //  console.log('x=' + x + ', y=' + y );
    }



    lastX = mouseX;
    lastY = mouseY;

  }
}

/*
       canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    
           if (mark)
               return;
           //get the img of convas
           
       });*/
//-------------- img zooms



function zoomin_canvas() {

  if (canvas != null) {

    var currWidth = canvas.clientWidth;
    //console.log('zoomin currWidth='+currWidth);
    if (currWidth >= 1500) return false;
    else {
      canvas.style.width = (currWidth + 100) + "px";


      //if (currScale < SCALE_MAX)
      //  currScale++;


      //console.log('scale=' + currScale);
    }
  }
}


function zoomout_canvas() {
  if (canvas != null) {
    var currWidth = canvas.clientWidth;

    if (currWidth <= 100) return false;
    else {
      canvas.style.width = (currWidth - 100) + "px";

      //if (currScale > SCALE_MIN)
      //  currScale--;


      //console.log('scale=' + currScale);
    }
  }
}

var currImgId = null;

function selectImg(e) {

  if (currImgId != null) {
    document.getElementById(currImgId).style.border = "none";

  }

  e.target.style.border = "2px solid orange";
  currImgId = (e.target).getAttribute('id');

  if (typeof canvas !== 'undefined') {
    // the variable is defined

    canvas = e.target;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  }
  //ctx.drawImage(img, 5, 40, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}

function rotate() {

  if (currImgId != null) {
    document.getElementById(currImgId).setAttribute("class", "rotated-image");
  }
}
var degrees = 0;

function rotateRight() {
  console.log('currimgid=' + currImgId);
  var img = document.getElementById(currImgId);
  degrees = parseInt(img.getAttribute("rotate"));
  degrees = (degrees + 90) % 360;
  img.style.setProperty('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
  img.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
  img.style.setProperty('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
  img.setAttribute("rotate", degrees);
}

function rotateLeft() {
  var img = document.getElementById(currImgId);
  degrees = parseInt(img.getAttribute("rotate"));
  degrees = (degrees - 90) % 360;
  img.style.setProperty('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
  img.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
  img.style.setProperty('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
  img.setAttribute("rotate", degrees);
}

function translate(X, Y) {

  console.log('untransformed x=' + X + ', y=' + Y);
  // const point = {x: 0, y: 0};
  const matrix = ctx.getTransform();
  const transformedPoint = {
    x: matrix.a * X + matrix.c * Y + matrix.e,
    y: matrix.b * X + matrix.d * Y + matrix.f,
  };
  console.log('transformed x=' + transformedPoint.x + ', y=' + transformedPoint.y);

}

function translateSimple(X, Y) {

  //console.log('scalefactor='+scaleFactor);
  console.log('untransformed x=' + X + ', y=' + Y);

  if (scaleFactor >= 1.0)
    console.log('transformed x=' + X / scaleFactor + ', y=' + Y / scaleFactor);
  else
    console.log('transformed x=' + X * scaleFactor + ', y=' + Y * scaleFactor);

}

function transformSimple(a) {

  //return (parseInt(a/(scaleFactor*scaleFactor)));

  if (currScale == 0)
    return (a);
  else

    return (a - 16 * (currScale));

}

function draw() {

  for (var x = 100; x < 102; x++)
    ctx.fillRect(100, x, 4.9, 4.9);

}
```

```css
.main_bottom {
  background-color: #e8e9eb;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 10px solid #e8e9eb;
  border-top: 30px solid #e8e9eb;
  height: 90vh;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.scrollit {
  /*overflow-y: auto;*/
  /* overflow-y: scroll;*/
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.first {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.submit {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.fix {
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#left_panel {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 700px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#right_panel {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 700px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#drag {
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 8px;
  cursor: w-resize;
}


/*img zooms*/

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #099;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -o-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

.main img {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
}


/*---- toggle switch*/

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 17px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196f3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(13px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(13px);
  transform: translateX(13px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 17px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.both {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>Order by Picture</title>
</head>


<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div id="navbar">
    <button type="button" onclick="zoomin_canvas()">+</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="zoomout_canvas()">-</button>
    <button id="rotateRight" onclick="rotateRight()">Right</button>
    <button id="rotateLeft" onclick="rotateLeft()">Left</button>
    <button id="Button1" onclick="draw()">draw</button
     <label> Marking</label>
     <label class="switch">
        
  <input type="checkbox" checked onclick="doMarking()" id="mark">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
  </div>

<div class="both">
<div class="canvas1">
<canvas id="canvas1" rotate="0" onclick="selectImg(event)" onmousedown="mouseDown(event)" onmouseup="mouseUp(event)" onmousemove="mouseMove(event)">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
</div>
<div class="canvas2">
 <canvas id="canvas2" rotate="0" onclick="selectImg(event)" onmousedown="mouseDown(event)" onmouseup="mouseUp(event)" onmousemove="mouseMove(event)">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
</div>
</div>
    </body>
   


    </html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't rotate the canvas

Draw the rotated image on the canvas, rather than rotate the canvas.

When you draw image on the canvas, rotate it, then you can draw over it using the normal mouse coords.

### Rotating image on canvas

The code below will draw an image rotated by any amount. The image will be scaled down if needed to ensure it fits the canvas. The function will rotate the image any angle you want.

```
// ctx is canvas 2D context
// deg in degrees rotated CW from 3 O-clock
// img to render. NOTE image must be loaded first
function drawRotatedImage(ctx, deg, img) { 
    const w = img.naturalWidth;
    const h = img.naturalHeight;
    const cw = ctx.canvas.width;
    const ch = ctx.canvas.height;
    
    // convert deg to radians
    const rad = deg * Math.PI / 180;
    
    // Get vector for rotated xAxis ax, ay. With aax, aay in first quadrant
    const ax = Math.cos(rad), aax =  Math.abs(ax);
    const ay = Math.sin(rad), aay =  Math.abs(ay);

    // get the rotated width and height of image
    const tw = aax * w + aay * h;
    const th = aay * w + aax * h;
    
    // get scale so that image fits the canvas. Dont enlarge only reduce if to big
    const scale = Math.min(1, cw / tw, ch / th);

    // set canvas transform to center of canvas, rotated and scaled to fit
    ctx.setTransform(ax * scale, ay * scale, -ay * scale, ax * scale, cw / 2, ch / 2);
    
    // draw image on canvas offset by half its width and height
    ctx.drawImage(img, -w / 2, -h / 2);
    
    // restore canvas transform to default
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); 
}
```

### Example

Example using the above function to render image to canvas and then use mouse to draw over the image. Click rotate to rotate the image.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const mouse = {x: 0, y: 0, b: false, ox: 0, oy: 0};
var rot = 90;
const img = new Image;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=420&g=1";
img.onload = () => rotImage(ctx, rot, img);
resize();
addEventListener("resize", resize);
rotBtn.addEventListener("click", () => img.complete && rotImage(ctx, rot += 90, img));
addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvent);
addEventListener("mousedown", mouseEvent);
addEventListener("mouseup", mouseEvent);
addEventListener("mouseout", mouseEvent);
function resize() {
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#00F";
    img.complete && rotImage(ctx, rot, img);
}
function mouseEvent(e) {
    mouse.ox = mouse.x;
    mouse.oy = mouse.y;
    mouse.x = e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY;
    if (e.type === "mousedown") { mouse.b = true }
    else if (e.type === "mouseup" || e.type === "mouseout") { mouse.b = false }     
    mouse.b && drawWithMouse(ctx, mouse);
}
function drawWithMouse(ctx, mouse) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.ox, mouse.oy);
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
function rotImage(ctx, deg, img) { 
    const cw = ctx.canvas.width, ch = ctx.canvas.height;       
    const w = img.naturalWidth, h = img.naturalHeight;
    const rad = deg * Math.PI / 180;
    const ax = Math.cos(rad), aax =  Math.abs(ax);
    const ay = Math.sin(rad), aay =  Math.abs(ay);
    const tw = aax * w + aay * h;
    const th = aay * w + aax * h;
    const sc = Math.min(1, cw / tw, ch / th);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.setTransform(ax * sc, ay * sc, -ay * sc, ax * sc, cw / 2, ch / 2);
    ctx.drawImage(img, -w / 2, -h / 2);
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); 
}
```

```css
* {font-family: arial;}
button { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px }
canvas { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>   
<button id="rotBtn">Rotate</button>
```